# Simulation of flow around a cylinder in OpenFOAM

Tags: methods, simulation, numeric, openfoam, fluid-dynamics

[Geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Qzt.png)

I have a made a geometry to simulate the flow around a cylinder using FreeCAD and exported it as .stl file. I am confused how to proceed next? I am using pitzDaily case directory for this simulation. Where to begin my simulation and which all files I need to alter?

I tried to change the vertices in blockMeshDict file but I failed. Can there be a technique in which I can import the stl file and the vertices can be updated automatically. Since, my geometry seems complicated after exporting it through MeshLab and there lot of vertices mentioned which I can not understand.